# How to create a link to already installed user applications

Tags: android

In my widget, when the widget is opened, I want it to open up a new page that shows links to the users already installed applications. The users must be able to add and delete the links as needed and the links would be updated if that application was deleted from the users device. I have already created the ability in my widget to open a new class but I don't know on how to go about linking to user applications. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the Activity of the app and link it with URI.

For example:

```
Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + facebookpackagename);
```

will load the Facebook app from within your app.

Try this code:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for(ApplicationInfo packageInfo:packages){
    if( pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName) != null ){
                String currAppName = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo).toString();
               //This app is a non-system app
    }
    else{
        //System App
    }
}
```

Comment: So is there a way I could automatically collect all the activites of the apps on the device and then have it link up to the URI? I am aware that using PackageManager is how I would collect a list of the users apps but then how would I go from there? I'm new to URI's so sorry if I'm asking too much. I'll start a new question later if necessary.

Comment: I've done some researching on URI's and understand it a bit, but if I can clarify really quick, I'd apperciate it. So basically, in my Uri.parse, I would indicate where the package is on the users device and then where would I go from there?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. Hope it helps you along the way of figuring out the solution. You are not asking too much. I am glad I can help you.